# How to get the index of a certain element?

Tags: xml, xpath, count

```
<documentRoot>
    <!-- Test data --> 
    <?value="2"?> 
    <parent name="data" > 
        <child id="1"  name="alpha" >Some Text</child> 
        <child id="2"  name="beta" > 
            <grandchild id="2.1"  name="beta-alpha" ></grandchild> 
          <grandchild id="2.2"  name="beta-beta" ></grandchild> 
        </child> 
        <pet name="tigger"  type="cat" > 
            <data> 
                <birthday month="sept"  day="19" ></birthday> 
                <food name="Acme Cat Food" ></food> 
            </data> 
        </pet> 
        <pet name="Fido"  type="dog" > 
            <description> 
                Large dog! 
            </description> 
            <data> 
                <birthday month="feb"  day="3" ></birthday> 
                <food name="Acme Dog Food" ></food> 
            </data> 
        </pet> 
    </parent> 
</documentRoot>
```

I want to get the index of a certain word in an element for all same elements in the document . In this case I want to get the index 2 for "Acme Dog Food" or 1 for "Acme Cat Food". I have tried:

```
count(//../food[contains(text(), 'Dog')]/preceding::food)
```

But I get an index 0.
I tried and tried here: http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code `contains(text(), 'Dog')` looks for elements with text inside them to contain 'Dog' (i.e. `<element>Dog</element>`. Instead, you are looking for the attribute "name" to contain dog, so the solution is:

```
count(//../food[contains(@name, 'Dog')]/preceding::food)
```

Note that this will get the quantity of elements before, but not the proper index. Indexes in XPath start in 1, not 0. To fix this, you just need to add `+1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I used this solution because with //../ looks in all the document.

Answer (score 0):

If you go two steps upwards, you can count the preceding siblings.

```
1+count(//food[@name="Acme Dog Food"]/../../preceding-sibling::pet)
```

The problem with your expression is that `Dog` is part of an attribute value, not a `text()` node.

Answer (score 0):

Try this XPath-1.0 expression

```
count(/documentRoot/parent/pet[data/food/@name = 'Acme Dog Food']/preceding-sibling::pet) + 1
```

or

```
count(//pet[data/food/@name = 'Acme Dog Food']/preceding-sibling::pet) + 1
```